# How to get textview string from inside recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Recyclerview contain cardlayout text1,text2 (id) two textviews.i want get text1 string value .if i touched one card.(touchlistner).how to print text1 string.i tried many nothing worked .

Comment: add your tried code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the **position** of your `recyclerView` list item. you can find the view with

```
TextView text1 = yourRecyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(position).itemView.findViewById(R.id.text1);
```

and then get `textView` string.

```
String text1Str = text1.getText().toString();
System.out.println("my textView string : " + text1Str);
```